# Stripping particular part from a path in python

Tags: python

I have a path which is something like this.

```
/schemas/123/templates/Template1/a/b
```

I want to strip off everything and store only the number (i.e. 123) to variable. Can someone help with this. And the number which I want to store stays at the same place in the path every time. I mean the number always comes after /schemas/"number"

Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

`pathlib` objects are designed for easy access to the component [parts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) of paths:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path('/schemas/123/templates/Template1/a/b')
>>> path.parts
('/', 'schemas', '123', 'templates', 'Template1', 'a', 'b')
>>> [int(part) for part in path.parts if part.isdigit()]
[123]
```

Comment: thanks so much for prompt reply. Is there any other way to achieve this without having to install any modules. Because my script is being used by lot of people around. I cant tell everyone to install this module. If you can suggest any other way without new modules thats really great.

Comment: `pathlib` is included in standard libs for more than 3 years now.  So anyone using a current version of Python does not have to install any extra modules, it comes with Python.

Comment: Follow the link in the answer and you will see, the module is part of the standard library :)

Comment: I have python 2.6.6. When i run the code by importing pathlib module, I get module error.

Comment: **Python 2.6 is nearly 10 years old now.**  Perhaps it's time for you to upgrade the Python version.

Comment: yeah i think its time to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** In the comments it is stated that it can be numbers and characters

**Method 1** Using split

```
#!/usr/bin/python
testLine = "/schemas/123abc/templates/Template1/a/b"
print testLine.split("/")[2]
```

**Method 2** Using regex

Select anything between the second and the third (*if exists*) slash

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

testLine = "/schemas/123abc/templates/Template1/a/b"
pattern = "^/schemas/(.[^/]+).*"
matchObj = re.match(pattern, testLine)

if matchObj:
    num = matchObj.group(1)
    print int(num)
else:
    print "not found"
```

The pattern is as follows:

- **^/** the string begins with slash
- **schemas/** next comes the word schemas with a slash in the end
- **(.[^/]+)** contains one or more characters excluding slash (parenthesis used for grouping)
- **.*** ends with any character

Comment: Thanks much. But for some reason it is not matching the pattern and resulting "not found". The "testline"  i have in my script is string. Is that causing any issue?

Comment: no testLine should be a string. Be careful the pattern is pretty strict, your testLine should start with "/schemas/" (also you can try to remove "^/")

Comment: Yeah i tested with that pattern as well and the path starts with /schemas. All I am suspecting is it because we are not specifying another after the number in pattern? Like it should accept what ever it comes after the "(\d+)" . Any ideas of how to do that?

Comment: You can try "^/schemas/(\d+)" or "^/schemas/(\d+).*"

Comment: "^/schemas/(\d+).*" This worked. But it is only picking up first three numbers. Ok, I have the number as mix of alphabets and numbers like 123abc. "(\d+)" is only picking up 123. How to denote this aplhanumeric thing?

Comment: Try this one "^/schemas/(.[^/]+).*" it grabs anything between the second slash and the third slash

Comment: I updated the answer also added a simpler method (using split)